# How does my Adapter know about notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView`, populated by a custom adapter:

```
public class myAdapter implements ListAdapter
```

This basic part is working - the views are created with the right data and all is good.

The data underlying the list will change occasionally, and I need to be able to cause the whole thing to refresh when it does.  I am struggling to work out how to do this.

`BaseAdapter` provides `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so I can make my class extend BaseAdapter:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter
```

but just calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my object does... well, nothing as far as I can see.  Certainly the `ListView` doesn't get updated and `myAdapter.getView()` is not called.

Calling `invalidate()` on the `ListView` also appears to have no effect.

It seems likely that my adapter needs to know about the possibility of data changing but I don't understand how to tie it all in with the `BaseAdapter` and/or `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does my Adapter know about notifydatasetchanged

under the hook `BaseAdapter` implements The `Observer` patter, and `notifyDataSetChanged`, notify the observer.

If you `implements ListAdapter` you have to provide your own version of `registerDataObser` and `unregisterDataObserver` . If you left those empty, `notifyDatasetChanged` does nothing. On the other hand `BaseAdapter implements ListeAdapter` and provides already the implementation for the above-quoted methods .

Comment: Thanks! Basically my adapter should just extend BaseAdapter and then all is well.